# L’étape prochaine d’entretien

Tags: sens

Am I right in thinking that *l’étape prochaine d’entretien...* can mean *l’étape prochaine, celle d’entretiens*, and does not have to refer to the next in a series of interview stages?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Maybe add the rest of the sentence. I’m struggling understanding the meaning of your words.

Comment: @grouah There isn't any more unfortunately. Imagine a selection process with a number of different stages - maybe candidates are just looked at on paper at the first stage, and then there is an interview stage. At the first stage, could you say e.g. *on verra ça lors de l'étape prochaine d'entretien*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to your question and comments, I would say that, in that context, *on verra ça lors de l'étape prochaine d'entretien* is understandable but not quite perfect. First, say *prochaine étape* rather than *étape prochaine*.

There's a little grammar subtlety. If you say *on verra ça lors de l'étape prochaine d'entretien*, then one could think that the first **and** the second stages were interviews.

If you say *on verra ça lors de l'étape prochaine **de l'** entretien*, then both stages are included in the term *entretien* (which therefore consists in two parts).

But if the context is that the first stage is not an interview but the second one is, then I would suggest to split into two propositions, like *On verra ça lors la prochaine étape, celle de l'entretien*, or (more idiomatic) *on verra ça à la prochaine étape, l'entretien*, or even *on verra ça à l'entretien*.

Comment: Many thanks. I was looking for a counterexample for a question I wanted to post on the linguistics SE - I'd hoped French might provide it but it seems it's the same as English in this respect.